# An unclear form in a song

Tags: song-lyrics, classical-japanese, subordinate-clauses

In「命火眩暈」by 杏ノ助, there are the following lines.

> 頽るる松、 甲羅なき亀 御簾を**上げれど** けふも宵

The other text is perfectly imitating a Sengoku-period Late Middle Japanese with occasional classical. However, this particular form is unexplicable to me. It look like a modern-language use. I can only understand it as if there was a 四段 verb あげる, which, according to the dictionary, never was; for an actual あぐ, which is 下二, the correct form would be あぐれど. What is happening, a carelessness of author or some unclear intent?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt [the lyrics](https://youtu.be/O-rXaKZXU1A) are "perfectly imitating a Sengoku-period Late Middle Japanese". This is not typical 古語 I learned at high school. 見**た** and 焼**い**て are modern 口語 and were not used in those days. 起きられ**ぬ** should probably be 起きられず. Therefore I would say 上げれど is also a simple mistake made by the author. Another possibility is that the author intentionally mixed the old and modern grammar and made pseudo-古文 for the sake of readability.

Comment: Of course it is hot 古文, but otherwise completely fits my ideas of Sengoku Middle Japanese with possible classic forms. However, a form like this is a mix of Edo-period modern inflection with an ancient ending.

Comment: @AlexanderZ Okay, then maybe the author and you know the grammar of 古文 much better than I :) If that's the case, I'm not qualified to answer this question. There are very few people who can make flawless 古文 these days...